# synchronous data processing from mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, asynccallback

[image]

**I have a problem with synchronous data processing:**

- In **task1.SO.mjs** file, I compute some parameters, then send to cloud mongoDB.
- In **task2.SISO.mjs** file, I take the parameters from **task1** after sending to the mongoDB cloud with the command **import task1**, and continue to calculate for task2.*

But my problem is:

Calculation speed and sending parameters into mongoDB of task1 are **too long**, so **task2 can't wait**, while it will take previous old result of task1 mongoDB to compute (not realtime), so result is incorrect.

**(?)** How can I process it **sequentially** while still using command **import task1** ?

I tried to use **delay** after import task1, but it's not ok.